# Problem with extracting data from an interpolating function generated by NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations

I have been trying for days to use the result of NDSolveValue. I have spent a lot of time on the forums and with the documentation trying different things and each one results in some different error. Below is a simple solution to the time dependent heat equation. Before I move on to the real problem, I would like to be able to extract interpolated values from the solution, get an animation, or even a plot from a slice in time. The code below tries to extract a value and plot a slice. Thanks

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 5, {x, y}];
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 100, x^2 + y^2 >= 5 && t > 0];
a = 1*10^-3;
soln = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] == a*Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}],
  boundary, u[0, x, y] == 0}, 
  u[t, x, y],
  {t, 0, 2},
  Element[{x, y}, region]
 ]
soln[1, 1, 1]

Plot3D[soln[1, x, y], {x, y} ∈ region,
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: Use `NDSolveValue[{..}, u, {t, 0, 2}, ..]` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, `Plot3D[soln /. t -> 1, {x, y} ∈ region]`

Answer (score 6):

When using [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), you have two basic choices for the return type, either a "function" or an "expression". For example, the following returns a "function":

```
r1 = NDSolveValue[{x'[t]+x[t]==Exp[t], x[0]==0}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
```

while the following returns an expression:

```
r2 = NDSolveValue[{x'[t]+x[t]==Exp[t], x[0]==0}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}];
```

With `r1` you can just use it the way you tried to in your example:

```
r1[.5]
```

> 0.521095

With `r2` you must use replacement rules:

```
r2 /. t->.5
```

> 0.521095

So, you should be using:

```
soln = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] == a*Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}],
    boundary, u[0, x, y] == 0}, 
    u, (* not u[t, x, y] *)
    {t, 0, 2},
    Element[{x, y}, region]
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know about that subtlety. I had tried the replacement rules, but got nowhere with that.